# BizTalk 2006 Long Running Transaction Issue

Tags: biztalk, biztalk2006r2

I am new to Biztalk and I am receiving this error (At first I wasnt worried but I have been receiving it daily for a week now) -

```
Severity:  Information
Status:  Resolved
Source:  Processor:  % Processor Time:  _Total
Name:  Copy of Production BizTalk CPU Util > 80%
Description:  Processor:  % Processor Time:  _Total value = 98.1562719649467
Domain:  TMM
Agent:  T00TNI01
Time:  8/28/2013 19:55:00
```

After some digging I believe that this is due to a long running transaction in BizTalk that is consuming over 80% of the CPU on the server. But how would I go about finding which transaction is causing the issue? Would I have to log onto the server or can I use the BizTalk Admin Console?

Comment: If I remember well, long running transactions are dehydrated, so they shouldn't use any CPU power, so maybe the orchestration has a loop somewhere?

Answer (score 2):

There is not enough information in the message alone. It seems like that you have periodic CPU utilization spikes that trigger monitoring alerts. There are many reasons for high CPU utilization: large message transformations, BAM tracking database overflow, any other compound reasons some of them may not be BizTalk related at all. But certainly, long running transaction is not the one to suspect. You have to do more troubleshooting. Download and run BizTalk MsgBoxViewer application to find out which host instance consuming high CPU. Even Task Manager can be useful to get a first look. Then you have a whole lot of BizTalk related performance counters in the Performance Monitoring MMC snap-in for detailed investigation.

Comment: +1 - that looks like a general Scom closure message. Quite often the various Wmi services used by scom can spike CPU - might not be Biztalk related at all. But check to see that the LRT's are being dehydrated.